# HTTPS via route53 to on-premise

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, cloud, amazon-route53

I have just installed Jenkins on an on-premise raspberry PI at home and I want to direct traffic to it via AWS.

So I have currently added an A record in route 53 to my network, but the problem is with the SSL certificate. And I guess that brings me to the question: how do you get SSL to on premise servers?

Answer (score 0):

Route53 is only a DNS server, which will forward the traffic for a configured domain name to your on-premise Raspberry PI's IP address (It should be having a public IP address). To include SSL, you will need to install an SSL certificate in Raspberry PI.

You can get a free SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). For more details, refer to the article on [Raspberry Pi SSL Certificates using Let’s Encrypt](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-ssl-lets-encrypt/).